# Where oh where is my FULLTEXT index?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Okay, I'm fully prepared to be told this is something dumb.  I've got a table like so:

```
mysql> show create table node\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: node
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `node` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `graph` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `predicate` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `object` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodeindex` (`graph`(20),`subject`(100),`predicate`(100),`object`(100)),
  KEY `ix_node_subject` (`subject`),
  KEY `ix_node_graph` (`graph`),
  KEY `ix_node_object` (`object`(255)),
  KEY `ix_node_predicate` (`predicate`),
  KEY `node_po` (`predicate`,`object`(130)),
  KEY `node_so` (`subject`,`object`(130)),
  KEY `node_sp` (`subject`,`predicate`(130)),
  FULLTEXT KEY `node_search` (`object`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=574161093 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the line `FULLTEXT KEY`node_search`(`object`)`.  When I try the query

```
mysql> select count(*) from node where match(object) against ('Entrepreneur');
```

I get the error

```
ERROR 1191 (HY000): Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

Duh?

#### Update

I tried an ANALYZE TABLE to no aval

```
mysql> analyze table node;
+------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| Table            | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| xxxxxxxxxxx.node | analyze | status   | OK       |
+------------------+---------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (21 min 13.86 sec)
```

Comment: [A quick test seems to work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1dc5/1), so no, I have no explanation for you :)

Comment: I just did an analyze table to see if maybe the index was somehow hosed; it completed fine.  I'm going to try to drop and recreate the index.